# Is there a word meaning hitting your mouth with something?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Like getting punched in the mouth. Or getting hit by the broom's handle when that one guy in front of you, who's carrying a broom, suddenly stopped.

Comment: You got *smacked in the pucker*.

Comment: I think I'd most naturally go with, "He stopped suddenly and I got whacked in the mouth by his broom."  But if he was swinging the broom and hit me in the mouth I'd go with, "I got whacked in the mouth ***with*** his broom." *Whack* is usually used when hitting something by swinging things.

Comment: Usually, the words relate to the object that hits (*what*), or the way it does (*how*), even maybe, *when*,  but seldom if ever, *where* it hurts!

Comment: *socked* .‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪.‪....

Comment: I believe "gobsmacked" literally refers to being hit in the mouth, but it's used only figuratively to mean "shocked."

Comment: @Brian is right, gobsmacked wouldn't be used to refer to actually being hit. Closest I can think of would be "chinned" (punched on the chin/jaw - "_he chinned me_") but I'm not sure that's in wide usage.

Comment: Given a knuckle sandwich? (Applies only in the case of being punched in the mouth, although "the broom gave him a knuckle sandwich" does have a certain ring to it!)

Comment: Punched "right in the kisser" is a common saying in my family. How does English have a word for poking someone's nose ("boop" - slang) but not getting hit in the mouth?

Comment: I've been in that situation a few times and several words came to mind.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers show that there are many words that mean to be hit in the mouth. The correct word depends on the object hitting the mouth.

For example, one could say, "I was hit in the mouth by a mop." A large percentage would think you were hit by the braided cloth end. A smaller percentage would think you were hit by the wood tip; and, a still smaller percentage would think you were hit by the body of the handle, like a baseball bat.

Now, to imply a certain attack, "I was slapped in the mouth by a mop," would more likely create the vision of a wet mop slapping and wrapping around the face."

"I was poked in the mouth by a mop," increases the likelihood of the reader imagining getting hit by the end of the wood handle.

To imply a thwack with the shaft, there are several colorful words. "I was (thwacked, high sticked, Babe Ruthed, beaten like Joe Pesci in Casino) in the mouth by a mop."

Answer (score 0):

The English language does not have a great word that specifically defines getting hit in the mouth, though the German language has one much closer 'Backpfeife'.

In English, I would always use the word socked (depending on the circumstance and audience of the piece being written); *"He was socked hard enough in the lips to split them wide open".*

Answer (score 0):

Although GOBSMACKED often refers to being utterly astonished or astounded, the online Urban Dictionary does give one meaning as getting literally hit in the mouth.
Their example is:
"I gobsmacked that bully with my biology book."

Comment: I've never encountered "gobsmacked" used in this literal sense.  Regardless of what the (notoriously unreliable as a reference) UD says, it's not a good recommendation.

Comment: @MaxWilliams It would probably be understood literally if used that way, but only by people whose dialect actually contains the word "gob" meaning "mouth", and from whose dialect the term originates.